# How to initialize and customize node structure in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

This question is going to be two parts.

1. I'd like to create a contenteditable div when `return` is entered, the new element will be `<p>`.  I searched out one solution is to define
   `document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p');`

   This works fine but the problem is when the div is initialized, the very first line will not be surrounded by `<p>`. It will be something like

   ```
   <div contenteditable=true>
       "hello"
       <p>new line here</p>
   </div>
   ```

I tried to put `<p>` tag in html, but it doesn't seem to work.

2. based on above question, it is possible to reach more rather than simply create new `<p>` for every new line. Can I create `<p><span</span></p>` for each line and the input text will be inserted into `<span>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for chrome and firefox

```
document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p');
  $('div[contenteditable="true"]').one('focus',function(){
    var selection=document.getSelection();
    var range=document.createRange();
    $(this).append("<p>&#8203;</p>");
    var insertedElement=$(this).find('p');
    range.setStart(insertedElement[0].firstChild,1);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  });
```